# "QUERY" add values without overwriting previous values

Tags: mysql, sql

im looking for way to do with a query to update the value **on specific field** without overwriting previous value.

- below code will overwriting previous value

  ```
  "UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '44@44.com' WHERE option_id = '2690'"
  ```

[image: screenshot of current table]

Comment: the best way would be to redesign your table structure to avoid the problem. You should have one row for each option_value. You can probably have more than one row with option_id 2690 and each of them store one option_value. Then you can insert a new value, delete it or update it easilly. You can add an ID column to have an unique identifier for each row

Comment: Please don't do it. It only complicates things . Redesign is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this with [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = CONCAT(option_value ,'44@44.com') WHERE option_id = '2690'
```

**As per comment** : You can use `COALESCE(str1,'')` or `IFNULL(str1,'')` to fix `null` value setting

Comment: **CAUTION:** `CONCAT(str1,str2)` will return `null` if either of the string (`str1 / str2`) is `null`. **Solution:** use `COALESCE(str1,'') or IFNULL(str1,'')`

Comment: @1000111 Thanks for the CAUTION, I've updated my answer as per your comment. :)

Comment: @Mostafa glad it works for you, I also suggest to see my edited answer for future `null` setting if any of the string is `null`